# Is there a way to send a user their current password if it is encrypted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, password-encryption

I have an app which encrypts user passwords using SHA1 and stores the hash in the database. I am wondering if it is possible for the user to request that their password be emailed to them if they forget it? Or would I have to store the passwords in plain text to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, if you've hashed it and stored only the hash then you're not going to be able to send them their password. That's one of the reasons for the hash really; for it to be very hard to go from the hash back to the original.

You don't want to be saving their password in the clear either. It may be useful to be able to send it to them but then you're keeping a treasure trove of passwords for someone who might gain access to your database.

Typically they'd have to change their password to something new if they've forgotten it rather than retrieving the existing password.

Answer (score 1):

No encryption mechanism is 100% secure, so it's possible you can crack the passwords and send them, but think for a moment about what you're trying to do. If you want to store the passwords securely, then this means making it infeasible to get them in clear text. If you're storing them in cleartext, then this negates having encrypted passwords in the first place, not to mention the security hole of sending them their password in a plaintext email.

Instead, consider using [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) directly, [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) (which uses bcrypt), or [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (which will handle performing password resets).